# Delphi: List All Windows Users Logged on a computer

Tags: delphi

I Developed an Application in Delphi 7 that runs as a windows service. I need this service catch all logged on users (this service will be installed on WTS server too).
I tried some codes I found in Web, but the service starts with system account, and the only thing that shows me as users is "System" or nothing.

I'm new at Delphi, so tanks for some help.

UPDATE:

Here is the actual code (very crazy) i'm using: I'm trying to run a MSDOS Command and get the return os command to Delphi. In Windows XP outside ActiveDirectory it works, but in Windows 7/8 inside ActiveDirectory show me nothing:

```
var     
  SA: TSecurityAttributes;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
  StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite: THandle;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  Buffer: array[0..255] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: Cardinal;
  WorkDir: string;
  Handle: Boolean;
  CommandLine: string;
  usuario: string;
begin
    totalinfo:= TStringlist.Create;
    try
      //--------------
      CommandLine:='WMIC COMPUTERSYSTEM GET USERNAME';
      with SA do begin
        nLength := SizeOf(SA);
        bInheritHandle := True;
        lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
      end;
      CreatePipe(StdOutPipeRead, StdOutPipeWrite, @SA, 0);
      try
        with SI do
        begin
          FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
          cb := SizeOf(SI);
          dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
          wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
          hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); // don't redirect stdin
          hStdOutput := StdOutPipeWrite;
          hStdError := StdOutPipeWrite;
        end;
        WorkDir := 'C:\';
        Handle := CreateProcess(nil, PChar('cmd.exe /C ' + CommandLine),
                            nil, nil, True, 0, nil,
                            PChar(WorkDir), SI, PI);
        CloseHandle(StdOutPipeWrite);
        if Handle then
          try
            repeat
              WasOK := ReadFile(StdOutPipeRead, Buffer, 255, BytesRead, nil);
              if BytesRead > 0 then
              begin
                Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
                usuario:=Buffer;
              end;
            until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);
              WaitForSingleObject(PI.hProcess, INFINITE);
          finally
            CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
            CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
          end;
      finally
        CloseHandle(StdOutPipeRead);
      end;
```

Tanks.

Comment: Without actual code no one can help you.

Comment: Windows Vista and newer now use different service profiles. These service profiles determine to what data or resources can service access. This was introduced to increase securty as it was to easy to register a service that has full acces to your entire computer before. So you might wanna read some more material on this and then determine the right way to start your service so that it is started with the right service profile.

Comment: There are no MS-DOS in Windows XP.

Answer (score 8):

Your service can use the [`WTSEnumerateSessions()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) and [`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx) functions, eg:

```
uses
  ..., Windows;

type
  WTS_INFO_CLASS = (
    WTSInitialProgram,
    WTSApplicationName,
    WTSWorkingDirectory,
    WTSOEMId,
    WTSSessionId,
    WTSUserName,
    WTSWinStationName,
    WTSDomainName,
    WTSConnectState,
    WTSClientBuildNumber,
    WTSClientName,
    WTSClientDirectory,
    WTSClientProductId,
    WTSClientHardwareId,
    WTSClientAddress,
    WTSClientDisplay,
    WTSClientProtocolType,
    WTSIdleTime,
    WTSLogonTime,
    WTSIncomingBytes,
    WTSOutgoingBytes,
    WTSIncomingFrames,
    WTSOutgoingFrames,
    WTSClientInfo,
    WTSSessionInfo,
    WTSSessionInfoEx,
    WTSConfigInfo,
    WTSValidationInfo,
    WTSSessionAddressV4,
    WTSIsRemoteSession
  );

  WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS = (
    WTSActive,
    WTSConnected,
    WTSConnectQuery,
    WTSShadow,
    WTSDisconnected,
    WTSIdle,
    WTSListen,
    WTSReset,
    WTSDown,
    WTSInit
  );

  PWTS_SESSION_INFO = ^WTS_SESSION_INFO;
  WTS_SESSION_INFO = record
    SessionId: DWORD;
    pWinStationName: LPTSTR;
    State: WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS;
  end;

const
  WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE: HANDLE = 0;

function WTSEnumerateSessions(hServer: THandle; Reserved: DWORD; Version: DWORD; var ppSessionInfo: PWTS_SESSION_INFO; var pCount: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll' name {$IFDEF UNICODE}'WTSEnumerateSessionsW'{$ELSE}'WTSEnumerateSessionsA'{$ENDIF};

function WTSQuerySessionInformation(hServer: THandle; SessionId: DWORD; WTSInfoClass: WTS_INFO_CLASS; var ppBuffer: LPTSTR; var pBytesReturned: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll' name {$IFDEF UNICODE}'WTSQuerySessionInformationW'{$ELSE}'WTSQuerySessionInformationA'{$ENDIF};

procedure WTSFreeMemory(pMemory: Pointer); stdcall; external 'Wtsapi32.dll';
```

```
var
  Sessions, Session: PWTS_SESSION_INFO;
  NumSessions, I, NumBytes: DWORD;
  UserName: LPTSTR;
begin
  if not WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, Sessions, NumSessions) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    if NumSessions > 0 then
    begin
      Session := Sessions;
      for I := 0 to NumSessions-1 do
      begin
        if Session.State = WTSActive then
        begin
          if WTSQuerySessionInformation(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, Session.SessionId, WTSUserName, UserName, NumBytes) then
          begin
            try
              // use UserName as needed...
            finally
              WTSFreeMemory(UserName);
            end;
          end;
        end;
        Inc(Session);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    WTSFreeMemory(Sessions);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new at Delphi World, so, when i use your code Delphi returns me: undeclared Identified: PWTS_SESSION_INFO. It uses some unit ? Tanks for answer my question ...

Comment: I added the declarations for you.

Comment: Sorry on more time, but in the line: "if not WTSEnumerateSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, 0, 1, Sessions, NumSessions) then" Delphi says me : [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(93): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE' ... What can I  do ?

Comment: Tank you Remy Lebeau !!! Your solution is perfect !! Worked very very fine as I wanted !!!

Comment: Thank you Remy Lebeau !!! your code is perfect but I think you need change `HANDLE` in `WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE: HANDLE = 0;` to `THandle`